# What is best way to calculate roots using recursion | C#

Tags: c#, math, recursion, console, root

I am learner of C#. And I love math. So when I learning recursion in C# I have one problem with calculate roots using recursion. Its simple if I use loop I can calculate it. But I have no idea with recursions. Can you give advice? 
Ex: Calculate using recursion with n = 5, 10 (n - number of the sequence)
NOTE: It's not homework or anything other. I am mathematic and only I want learn way to calculate. 
Thanks
[image: Image Of Root Here]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try code like below.  You will need some minor changes :

```
        static double Root(int number, int multiplier, int level)
        {
            double results = 0;
            if (level > 0)
            {
                results = Root(number, multiplier, level - 1); 
            }
            if (level % 2 == 0)
            {
                results += multiplier * Math.Sqrt(number);
            }
            else
            {
                results -= multiplier * Math.Sqrt(number);
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, But I thinks its not same as with my question?

Comment: I was giving a sample of recursion code.  I know it isn't exactly the same as you code posted.  I wasn't 100% sure in the first example how the plus and minus signs were changing.  I guess you have to use mod 3 instead of mod 2.